# Counting error values as any other value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a list of data as shown below. I am trying to count how many occurences there are of each unique value.

But some of these values are error values, such as `#N/A`. Is there a formula that can count both regular values and error values?

This one (entered as an array formula) can count the `a`'s and other regular values:

```
=SUM(--IFERROR($A$2:$A$14=C2,FALSE))
```

But if I copy it down, obviously it doesn't work for the error value totals, because it ignores the errors using `IFERROR`.

I know I can count the `#N/A`'s using this:

```
=SUM(--ISNA($A$2:$A$14))
```

but it's a different formula entirely; I can't just drag-copy it down the column.

I'm looking for a formula that can accommodate both without "changing the source code".

`COUNTIF` does count them properly, but I don't think I can use it, as this is only meant to be a piece of a larger array formula.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it looks like COUNTIF correctly counts both regular values and error codes.

Comment: @user3964075: Dang, that's right. Thing is, I'm not sure I can use `COUNTIF`, because this is going to go into a larger array formula!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you not able using `COUNTIF`, try following formula in `D2`

```
{=SUM(IFERROR($A$2:$A$14=C2,FALSE)+IFERROR(ERROR.TYPE($A$2:$A$14)=ERROR.TYPE(C2),FALSE))}
```

Answer (score 1):

`=SUM(--IF(ISERROR(C2),IF(ISNA(C2),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14,"#N/A"),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14,"#VALUE!")),IFERROR($A$2:$A$14=C2,FALSE)))`

It looks like this accomplishes what you want, and works for me in an array formula.

[image]

Comment: Axel Richter's appears to accomplish the same as mine, but cleaner and encompasses all of the error values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small *UDF()*:

```
Public Function Kount(rng As Range, what As Variant) As Long
    Dim r As Range, st1 As String, st2 As String
    st1 = CStr(what)
    For Each r In rng
        st2 = r.Text
        If st1 = st2 Then
            Kount = Kount + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

In this sample both **C4** and **C5** are text values.

Comment: This is indeed trivial in VBA.